# tabulator, I need to know how to click on a cell and change the value in another column of the same row that I clicked

Tags: tabulator

I need to know how to do the following exercise,
I am using Tabulator as a grid, I have 4 columns, only one of them must be checked, until there everything is fine, but the functionality I need is that if I click on another of the three columns that are not marked, only the one I made click should be checked and the other 3 without mark.
And of course I need to know how to click on a cell and change the value in another column of the same row that I clicked.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

thanks for your response Michael, tests and more tests and I succeeded, my result is a bit orthodox but it works as I expected, **if you have a better performance function**, please let me know.

my explanation of what i need:
I have 6 columns, the first one keeps information of the click that is made in the next 4, but in those 4 columns only one can be marked, and the sixth column provides additional information that is included in the first. It is not my native language but I hope I have explained it in the best way.

My way to do:

```js
{title:"Nivel", field:"nivel", sorter:"string", align:"center"},
            {title:"Consultar", field:"consultar",formatter:checkboxIcon,cellClick:rowCheck,headerVertical:true,align:"center"},
            {title:"Crear", field:"crear",formatter:checkboxIcon,cellClick:rowCheck,headerVertical:true,align:"center"},
            {title:"Modificar", field:"modificar",formatter:checkboxIcon,cellClick:rowCheck,headerVertical:true,align:"center"},
            {title:"Eliminar", field:"eliminar",formatter:checkboxIcon,cellClick:rowCheck,headerVertical:true,align:"center"},
            {title:"Reportes", field:"reportes",formatter:checkboxIcon,cellClick:rowCheck,headerVertical:true,align:"center"},

function rowCheck(e, cell) {

    repor = cell.getData().nivel.substr(1,1);
    nivel = cell.getData().nivel.substr(0,1);
    if (nivel==='R') {
        repor=nivel;
        nivel='';
    }

    row = cell.getRow();
    if (cell.getColumn().getField() !== 'reportes') {
        if (cell.getValue()==='1') {
            row.update({'consultar': '', 'crear': '', 'modificar': '', 'eliminar': ''});
            cell.setValue('');
        } else {
            row.update({'consultar': '', 'crear': '', 'modificar': '', 'eliminar': ''});
            cell.setValue('1');
        }
    } else {
        if (cell.getValue()==='1') {
            cell.setValue('0');
            repor='';
        } else {
            cell.setValue('1');
            repor='R';
        }
    }


    switch (cell.getColumn().getField()) {
        case "consultar":
            if (cell.getValue()==='1') { nivel = '0' } else { nivel = '' }
            //row.update({'nivel':'0'+repor});
            break;
        case "crear":
            if (cell.getValue()==='1') { nivel = '1' } else { nivel = '' }
            //row.update({'nivel':'1'+repor});
            break;
        case "modificar":
            if (cell.getValue()==='1') { nivel = '2' } else { nivel = '' }
            //row.update({'nivel':'2'+repor});
            break;
        case "eliminar":
            if (cell.getValue()==='1') { nivel = '3' } else { nivel = '' }
            //row.update({'nivel':'3'+repor});
            break;
        case "reportes":
            if (cell.getValue()==='1') { repor = 'R' } else { repor = '' }
            //row.update({'nivel':nivel+repor});
            break;
        default:
    }
    row.update({'nivel':nivel+repor});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

so you want radioButton like functionality on a per-row basis ? Is it only 1 row ? or is it a grid like you said, and there's only 1 check mark for the entire grid ?